# 'floor': identifier not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, math.h

My code was working fine until suddenly I am receiving this message when compiling:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\math.h(700): error C3861: 'floor': identifier not found
```

I tried to exclude math.h, but I got the same message. when I double click on the message, it takes me to line 700 of file math.h, which uses function floor.

Then, I made an empty project with just one file consisted of only:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
}
```

And I am still getting that error. Have I accidentally deleted something? How can I understand what it is?

Comment: Clean up, reinstall and reboot ;(

Comment: try a clean and rebuild of the project.

Comment: @DieterLücking: Rebooting would be overkill. Cleaning and rebuilding the project should be sufficient.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Standard help-desk advice. Always tell them to reboot. http://dilbert.com/strip/2003-03-02

Comment: I started a whole new project with those few lines, cleaned and rebuilt, rebooted, nothing works

Comment: If this happens in all projects, maybe your installation is broken, I would try running repair (Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> find your Visual Studio version -> Change -> Repair).

Comment: What exactly does "nothing works" mean? Are you still getting an error message referring to `floor`?

Comment: You didn't create your own file called "math.h", did you?

Comment: `math.h` should *declare* the `floor` function (and may also use it)\. What's on line 700? Is there a declaration of `floor` earlier in the file? It's plausible that the `<iostream>` depends on `math.h`; what happens if you make an empty project *without* `#include <iostream>` on the first line?

Comment: No, I did not creat a file named math.h, and an empty project with including only iostream returns that error too. Nothing works means all the things that I mentioned before that: whole new project with those few lines, cleaned and rebuilt, rebooted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite strange behavior for MSVS.

1) Try to create empty project (without precompiled headers)

2) Try changing

```
#include <math.h>
```

to

```
#include <cmath>
```

If this not help as well as creation of new empty project, the only way is to ensure that no viruses at your PC and re-install Visual Studio

Comment: The empty project without 
    #include <math.h> 
returns the same error only by including 
#include <iostream>

Comment: I tried repair, it did not work. Then tried uninstalling and reinstalling Visual studio and everything is fine now